# using ajax ready function inside of an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, ready

I'm loading a webpage in an iframe.  That page uses the jquery .ready function to load content when the page is "ready".  It appears that the .ready function is firing too soon.

All of the solutions I find when I search involve an event fired on the main page (not on the iframe page).  Is there anything I can do in the source of the page that loads inside the iframe to make the .ready function fire later, or is there some other function or event I can use that will work?  I'd prefer not to use an arbitrary timeout function, since that can lead to unnecessary delays or may not be a long enough wait in some conditions.

Edit:  The page I'm loading in the iframe, works just fine when it's loaded on it's own directly in a browser.

Comment: Can you post code of your iframe page...where you are using jquery ready function.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery.load() method which will get trigger only the entire page is loaded (including all content).

sample

```
$(window).load(function(){

});
```

note:
if you intent to use .load() function, then you should not use .ready() function.